# Rails 4 Unpermitted Parameters for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have an array field in my model and I'm attempting to update it.

My strong parameter method is below

```
def post_params
  params["post"]["categories"] = params["post"]["categories"].split(",")

  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :categories)
end
```

My action in my controller is as follows

```
def update
  post = Post.find(params[:id]

  if post and post.update_attributes(post_params)
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    redirect_to posts_url
  end
end
```

However, whenever I submit the update the post, in my development log I see

```
Unpermitted parameters: categories
```

The parameters passed through is

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"auth token", "id"=>"10", 

"post"=>{"name"=>"Toni Mitchell", "email"=>"eileen_hansen@hayetokes.info", "categories"=>",2"}}
```

I want to think it has something to do with the fact that the attribute `categories` is an array since everything else looks fine. Then again, I could be wrong. So, what's wrong with my code and why is not letting me save the categories field when clearly it is permitted to do so? Thanks.

Comment: It might be due to the way you are setting the value of the categories parameter, iirc the params object is not a simple hash, have you tried a simpler example?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Try this

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :categories => [])
```

(Disregard my comment, I don't think that matters)

Comment: hi,i have a problem Bid(#69846105528920) expected, got String(#8248680)

Comment: Hi there, is there a way to find a post depending on the categories in the array, example `Post.find_by(tags: 'sports')` ?

Comment: It would be nice to also explain why this works @slicedpan

Answer (score 46):

in rails 4, that would be,

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, {:categories => []})
```

Comment: This works for me but why does it need to be in a separate hash if we already defined the serialization of that attribute in the model?

Answer (score 10):

The permitted scalar types are `String`, `Symbol`, `NilClass`, `Numeric`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime`, `StringIO`, `IO`, `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` and `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`.

To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

```
params.permit(:id => [])
```

This is what the [strong parameters documentation on Github](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) says:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :categories => [])
```

I hope this works out for you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but simply adding array to permit was not enough. I had to add type, too. This way:

```
params.require(:transaction).permit(:name, :tag_ids => [:id])
```

I am not sure if this is perfect solution, but after that, the 'Unpermitted parameters' log disappeared.

I found hint for that solution from this excellent post: http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple items and item_array inside parameters like this-

```
Parameters {"item_1"=>"value 1", "item_2"=> {"key_1"=> "value A1", 
"key_2"=>["val B2", "val C3"]} }
```

There we have array inside `item_2`.
That can be permit as below-

```
params.permit(item_2: [:key_1, :key_2 => [] ])
```

Above saved my day, may be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case I had also to change from:

`<input type="checkbox" name="photographer[attending]" value="Baku">`

to:

`<input type="checkbox" name="photographer[attending][]" value="Baku">`

Hope this is helping someone.