# Rails 4 unpermitted parameters for multi tag input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have working code that uses [select2](https://select2.github.io) to accept multiple tags into the one input field. I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150748/1299792) to permit my parameter as:

`params.require(:computer_service).permit( {:repairer_ids => []})`

This works correctly. I recently set Rails to raise an error for unpermitted errors so I would be aware if any form data wasn't being saved:

```
#development.rb
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

Since adding that setting Rails now raises an error `found unpermitted parameters:  repairer_ids`, even though the code works and the parameter repairer_ids are found and saved.

Sample parameters:

`"computer_service"=>{ "repairer_ids"=>"1663,1726" }`

**UPDATE**

If I change to `params.require(:computer_service).permit( :repairer_ids )` then the first id is saved but not the second. I should point out that in my controller I am using code to convert the comma separated string into an array:

```
@computer_service.repairer_ids = repairer_ids.split(',')
```

I am doing this because the relationship between ComputerService and Repairer is a has_many through

```
#computer_service.rb
has_many :repairers, :through => :computer_service_repairers
```

and I have successfully saved multiple values to the **computer_service_repairers** through/join table by using multiple values in an array.

Comment: Your `repairer_ids` aren't being received in an array form. Try `params.require(:computer_service).permit(:repairer_ids)`

Comment: Agree with @Humza - Looks like the the input is being submitted as a comma delimited string, not an array.

Comment: @Humza, thank you for your help. I forgot to put in my original question that I was manually converting to an array in my controller so I could use a has_many through relationship with a join table. My apologies. I have updated the question.