# Unpermitted parameter for array with dynamic keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to permit an array with an arbitrary number of values, but Rails throws `Unpermitted parameter: service_rates` every time. I tried a lot of things ([Rails 4 Unpermitted Parameters for Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868746/rails-4-unpermitted-parameters-for-array), [Unpermitted parameters for Dynamic Forms in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189602/unpermitted-parameters-for-dynamic-forms-in-rails-4), ...) but nothing works.

The field's name is `service_rates` and it's column type is `jsonb`.

I want to create a JSON object from an arbitrary number of input fields:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service_ids, value: @services.map(&:id) %>
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <% value = @project.service_rates ? @project.service_rates["#{service.id}"]['value'] : '' %>
      <%= text_field_tag "project[service_rates][#{service.id}]", value, class: 'uk-width-1-1', placeholder: 'Stundensatz' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

So my `POST` data looks like this:

```
 project[service_rates][1] = 100
 project[service_rates][2] = 95
 project[service_rates][3] = 75
```

Currently `service_rates` is permitted via whitelisting with `tap`:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:field1, :field2, […], :service_ids).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:service_rates] = params[:project][:service_rates]
  end
end
```

At least, I'm building a JSON object in a private model function (which throws this error):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :assign_accounting_content

  attr_accessor :service_ids

  private

  def assign_accounting_content

    if self.rate_type == 'per_service'
      service_rates = {}
      self.service_ids.split(' ').each do |id|
        service_rates["#{id}"] = {
          'value': self.service_rates["#{id}"]
        }
      end

      self.service_rates = service_rates
    end

  end

end
```

I've also tried to permit the field like that …

```
params.require(:project).permit(:field1, :field2, […], :service_rates => [])
```

… and that …

```
params.require(:project).permit(:field1, :field2, […], { :service_rates => [] })
```

… but this doesn't work either.

When I try this …

```
params.require(:project).permit(:field1, :field2, […], { :service_rates => [:id] })
```

… I get this: `Unpermitted parameters: 1, 3, 2`

Comment: Are you able to dump your request object (what it looks like before it is passed to strong parameters?) I ran into this recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what `service_rates` is for you. Is it the name of an association ? Or just an array of strings ?

To allow array of strings : `:array => [],`
To allow nested params for association : `association_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, ...]`

```
params.require(:object).permit(
  :something,
  :something_else,
  ....
  # For an array (of strings) : like this (AFTER every other "normal" fields)
  :service_rates => [],
  # For nested params : After standard fields + array fields
  service_rates_attributes: [
    :id,
    ...
  ]
)
```

As I explained in the comments, the order matters. Your whitelisted array must appear AFTER every classic fields

**EDIT**

Your form should use `f.fields_for` for nested attributes

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :service_rates do |sr| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= sr.text_field(:value, class: 'uk-width-1-1', placeholder: 'Stundensatz' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. `service_rates` is an object (of objects), not an array. Is it possible to permit a hash with arbitrary (nested) keys and values?

Comment: Well, accepting an arbitrary number of keys and values is the opposite of Rails 4 strong params. It is not safe to do that. But you can still access the parameters with `params[service_rates]`

Comment: Would it be possible to permit keys dynamically? The content of `service_rates` looks like `'1': {'value': 10, 'active': true }, '2': {'value': 20, 'active': false }`. The keys (`1`, `2`, …) are IDs of the records from my `Service` model. Would this work: `permit({:service_rates => { HOW_TO_ADD_ALL_SERVICE_IDS_HERE? }})`?

Comment: Oh you meant that. This is done automatically, you don't have to worry about it. When you write `service_rates_attributes: ` it will automatically permit the array of `service_rates`, so you just have to specify `service_rates_attributes: [:id, :value, :active]`

Comment: When I do this, I get `Unpermitted parameter: service_rates` :( (I'm using Rails 4.2.3)

Comment: I think the problem is in your form/model. You should edit your question to add them. I also added an edit to my answer.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I've used a weird mix of same-named input fields and params. I refactored parts of my code and now it works. Thank you very much!